# Map function for objects

Tags: javascript

I have been using underscore.js' map function which does a great job for me. I am looking for a way to replicate this using pure javascript.

```
var fields = _.map(data.filters, function(values, key) {
    var name = key.replace(/(_Range|_Options)$/, "");
    var data = values[0];
    var min = data.min;
});
```

So basically, this takes an object and does some operation on each element and return an array of objects.
There is Array.map(). What I am looking for is a solution that allows me to pass an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of keys, and then you can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

**Note:** don't forget the return from the map, or the result would be an array of `undefined`.

```
var fields = Object.keys(data.filters).map(function(key) {
    var name = key.replace(/(_Range|_Options)$/, "");
    var data = data.filters[key][0];
    var min = data.min;

    return {
      name,
      data
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
function forEach(object, fn) { 
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object).map(key => fn(key, object[key])); 
}
```

And usage:

```
forEach({"a":1,"b":2}, (k, v) => console.log(k, v));
```